# Custom Field: Multiple Contact References

Tags: custom-fields

Is it possible to configure custom field of type contact reference to store multiple contacts?

Comment: Maybe not exactly the same but how about add a set of custom fields that allows multiple (where it says "Does this Custom Field Set allow multiple records?"), then add one custom field in that group that is a contact reference?

Comment: Unfortunately its for Contribution

Comment: @PradeepNayak - I don't suppose you found a solution for this?

Comment: Nope ended up creating multiple fields

Comment: @PradeepNayak - thanks anyway!

Comment: @PradeepNayak - see https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2123

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in CiviCRM 5.34+: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2123